# How to check if key exists inside JSON file, if the key is inside an Array in JSON (ROBOT FRAMEWORK)

Tags: python, arrays, json, collections, robotframework

So I am facing this problem, where I need to check if the key exists in my JSON file, and continue my actions based on that. So I am doing

```
Add Item To JSON
    [Documentation]     This keyword is designed to add an Item to JSON file
    [Arguments]         ${json_file}    ${item_ref}

    ${item_details}        Create Dictionary   something=${some_string}
    #Adding all my details here

    ${item_list}          Create List         ${item_details}

    #Check if there are any items already added to Add item To JSON
    ${is_item_key_exist}   Run Keyword And Return Status  Dictionary Should Contain Key   ${json_file}  Items

    # If Items key does not exists, then add the item to JSON
    IF  ${is_item_key_exist}
       ${json_file}=    Add Object To Json   ${json_file}   $..Items   ${item_details}

    #Otherwise create Items key and add details into it
    ELSE
       ${items}   Create Dictionary     Items=${item_list}
       ${json_file}=   Add Object To Json   ${json_file}     $.value.containers[0]   ${items}
    END

    [Return]    ${json_file}
```

And this is what my json looks like

```
"containers": [
  {    "Items": [
      {
        "emptyFullIndicatorCode": "1/1",
        "emptyWeight": "0",
        "goods": "goods",
        "goodsWeight": "1",
        "numberOfPackages": "1",
        "packagingTypeCode": "PK",
        "packagingTypeName": "Colis (\"package\")",
        "reference": "YYYY1234567",
        "typeCode": "18R0"
      }
    ]
  }
```

So in this scenario, when There is actual Key Items inside the JSON, my code returns false on the check if the key is actually there.
I assume it's because the key Items is inside an array that is inside another key Containers, but I could not find a solution how to pinpoint to it.

Tried accessing it via different keywords form Collections.py library but I never get it right.
If I try to do same scenario with checking the Containers key - it works fine.

Comment: Could you highlight in your example JSON what you want to find and what your expected output is? I.e Given Func("PK") = True? or Func("package") = TRUE? Also do you have a fixed depth to go or is it a worse case fully recursive algorithm you are looking for ?

Comment: What i want to do, is to find out why
   ${is_item_key_exist}   Run Keyword And Return Status  Dictionary Should Contain Key   ${json_file}  Items
IF  ${is_item_key_exist}
line is not working, and it always throws False, where obviously the Items key is there inside the Json

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the JSON in its format? I.e you could reformat it to be a proper one without the array/list and your robotframework code should then be okay. Otherwise a conditional check if the result of the key is an array and do another check for keys for each array.

Comment: @JasonChia yes it's necessary for me to keep it in the format it is, as it should be later on be passed as request body - so when I try to change it the request simply does not work

Answer (score 0):

@The Leviathan, I am not so familiar with robotframework but consider the following python recursion:

```
def check_keys(search_key,data):
    return_value = False
    for key,value in data.items():
        if search_key == key:
            return_value = True
        else:    
            dict_test = check_list(search_key,value) #<-recursion
            if dict_test:
                  return_value = True
            else:
                 pass
    return return_value
                    

def check_list(search_key,x): #Checks that the 'value' is not a list containing a dict.
    return_value = False
    if isinstance(x,list):
        for item in x:
            if isinstance(item,dict):
                return_value = check_keys(search_key,item)
    return return_value
```

Basically checks each value if there is another layer of dict inside.

```
x = {"containers": [
  {    "Items": [
      {
        "emptyFullIndicatorCode": "1/1",
        "emptyWeight": "0",
        "goods": "goods",
        "goodsWeight": "1",
        "numberOfPackages": "1",
        "packagingTypeCode": "PK",
        "packagingTypeName": "Colis (\"package\")",
        "reference": "YYYY1234567",
        "typeCode": "18R0"
      }
    ]
  }]}

check_keys('containers',x) -> True
check_keys('Items',x)->True
check_keys('goodsWeight',x)->True
check_keys('magic',x) -> False
```

Not sure how to implement in robotframework but this is a recursive solution that does not modify the JSON, and probably not optimal as well.